# Can I use the Arcane Gate spell as an auto kill?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, portals

The *arcane gate* spell says the any matter passing through the
right side of the one of the portals comes out of the right side of the other portal.

So, I noticed that if you put the two portals next to each other with the right sides facing each other it could potentially grind anything passing through it into a nasty lump. The way I think this would work is anything going through one portal immediately comes out the other one which would result in it coming out *inside* itself in a manner similar to microphone feedback.
Is this valid?

Comment: Can you explain more about what part of the spell you think is able to be read as grinding something into a lump? I don't see how you are setting this up yet honestly. Maybe doing a diagram and quoting the exact part of the spell you are using to create this effect would be helpful here.

Comment: I *think* I'm on board. If I understand the scenario, it goes like this: the two portals face each other like so `|  |` then a dude throws a basketball or a rock or another dude into one—like from above and between the two portals and—because the two portals are so close—the item goes back and forth between them at impossible speeds. Is that accurate?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Portals have to be perpendicular to the ground "hovering inches from the ground and perpendicular to it at the points you choose" so I'm not sure that example is possible. How is the object gaining speed?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I don't think it would be *gaining* speed so much as moving near instantaneously between the two portals because the distance between portals is littler than the size of the object being shuttled between portals. I'm imagining whatever's between ending up suspended between yet in constant motion? Or something? Like I said, I'm not challenging anything but speculating and trying to clarify—I don't know if this is what the asker has in mind at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: Apparently commenters and answerers don't "get what you mean".  How about you explain it more specifically.

Comment: Do you mean coming out of the portal into the back of the other? Effectively into a magic wall?

Comment: I understand what he means. Imagine the portal works like stargate only you walk out the other end at the same time and rate that you walk in the first side. So if the active side of both portals are facing each other he will still be walking in one portal while he is walking out of the other portal which his body is currently passing through while entering the first portal. This basically assumes that you do not have to fully enter one portal before you start exiting the other, and part of your body magically comes out in the space that your body is already occupying.

Comment: YES! That is exactly what I mean!

Comment: I accepted (and added some minor corrections) to ninjageckos' edit, as it seems to correspond about OP point based on previous comments just above. Feel free to roll back if you think that this changes too much the question.

Comment: So I see the edits have been rolled back. @ninjagecko, if there's any aspect of the question you're still looking for (and which isn't covered by the answers), I'll suggest asking a new question with your specific situation. As it stands, this is probably better left for the querent to clarify, or just as is. QPaul, If you want to there is now a version in the rev history if you want to look towards getting the question reopened.

Comment: Draw a picture; that's my suggestion. It may help clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Probably Not, But Ask Your DM

And preferably in-game.

In the words of a famous D&D philosopher:

> You can certainly try

The rules of the *arcane gate* spell do not specify what happens if you put the two portal faces facing each other.  There is nothing that I'm aware of in any other rule in the rule books that would, by the rules, result in some sort of auto-grinding situation.

Therefore, like so many things, even within the rules, it ends up with a DM's interpretation.  So, in order to find out what happens in this case, you may need to resort to the fundamental rule of D&D (from the Player's Handbook):

> 1. The DM describes the environment.
> 2. The players describe what they want to do.
> 3. The DM narrates the results of the adventurers’ actions.

In many easy cases, it is possible for the sages here on rpg.se to make some pretty sound speculations based on careful reading of the rules.  However, it always comes down to what a DM decides in a given game.

My own opinion, as a DM, I think I could decline to provide a player with an omniscient answer to that.  Instead, I would probably suggest they ask in game, and I would probably have a character asking make an arcana check, and then answer somewhere along the lines of, "You're not sure, but thinking back to your schooling, you think it probably wouldn't work that way.  Magic is . . . magical after all. You're pretty sure you'd have to try it to be sure", or possibly more or less certainty or description depending on the roll.

On the other hand, get those portals oriented right and those goblins might well run right into the fighter, the rogue, and the ranger, all holding lots of sharp pointy things.  That might result in some pretty awesome grinding, chopping, and lumping.

Answer (score 7):

## No, you can't.

When you enter one side of a portal you come out the corresponding active side of the other portal.

> Any creature or object entering the portal exits from the other portal as if the two were adjacent to each other; passing through a portal from the nonportal side has no effect.

If you put two portals near each other and with their active sides facing towards each other you'll end up continuously moving back and forth between the portals at the speed you enter them. This seems like it would possibly be very difficult for a creature to get out of, but would not cause them any damage as they wouldn't be teleported until they fully entered the portal and then their entire body is teleported. Their entire body can only be within one portal at the same time, so it wouldn't tear them apart or anything like that.

Nowhere does the spell ever say or imply that it can be used to harm or destroy anything at all, much less "auto kill" something. And it doesn't seem possible to force any interaction between the portals that would cause this to happen either.

Comment: You don't understand. I mean if you place the right sides of the portals facing _together_.

Comment: @QPaul No one seems to understand, maybe you should explain it better